# Consolidating duplicates with preg_replace, take into consideration dash

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a preg_replace that finds duplicate entries and consolidates. I need to take into consideration the dash as well, but currently it does not.

```
$id = KRS-KRS-123
preg_replace('/^(\w+)-(?=\1)/', '', $id);
// returns KRS-123

$id = KRS-KRS123
preg_replace('/^(\w+)-(?=\1)/', '', $id)
// returns KRS123
// I need this one to return KRS-KRS123
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a word boundary, `\b`, after the `\1` inside the look ahead `(?=\1\b)`:

```
preg_replace('/^(\w+)-(?=\1\b)/', '', $id);
```

That way, the lookahead will only evaluate to true if `\1` is followed by a `\W` (a `[^\w]`) or the end-of-string.

### Demo

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
$s = 'KRS-KRS-123
KRS-KRS123';
echo preg_replace('/^(\w+)-(?=\1\b)/m', '', $s);
?>
```

will produce:

```
KRS-123
KRS-KRS123
```